# Database Login Error

Tags: sql-server

When I try to connect to database I get Database Login Error. The connection I use is `"Data Source=IK-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog='abc.new';Persist Security Info=True;User Id=IK-PC\\Administrator"`

- My server name: IK-PC\SQLEXPRESS
- My authentication is Window Authentication
- My user name is IK-PC\Administrator.

Everything is shown on SQL Management Studio Connect to Server form.And my database name is abc.new, which is attached to the SQLMS.

Comment: I am connecting from a user form.

Comment: Well yes it wants the password.. What are you actually trying to do? Have your application connect as admin to do something special, or is it an app you have to be an admin to run. e.g. Run as Admin and integrated security =SSPI would appear to be the way you should be going, given your windows admin user is an admin user on the db server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a Windows login in SQL Server, you should use `Integrated Security=True` (or `Integrated Security=SSPI`) instead of user Id and password.

```
"Data Source=IK-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog='abc.new';Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True"
```

You need to then run the process accessing SQL Server as IK-PC\Administrator user.